# writing nested dictionary in the csv file, but the header is getting repeated / appended for each time in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie to python. I've coded to append nested dictionary in the csv file. but the header is also getting apended each time when I run the code.

But I need, the header should need to be appended only once in the csv file not more than that.

Is there any modification that you suggest which will helpful for me..

Thanks in Advance.

```
                       CSV file output
```

CSV file screenshot

[image]

```
User ID Name    Age Occupation  Department  Salary  Address

1100    Vishal  24  Data Scientist  Analytics   75000   No.341, Kannagi Nagar, Okkiyam Thoraipakkam, chennai 97

User ID Name    Age Occupation  Department  Salary  Address

1101    MuraliKrishnan  45  Painting contractor Contract    50000   No.341, Kannagi Nagar, Okkiyam thoraipakkam, chennai 97
```

```
import csv

user_details = {}

while True:
    user_input = input(" You're Operation Please ( New / View ) Details : ").lower()

    if user_input == 'new':
        create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
        user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
        user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
        user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age
        user_occupation = input(" Enter the users occupation : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Occupation'] = user_occupation
        user_department = input(" user department : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Department'] = user_department
        user_income = int(input(" Enter the salary details : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Salary'] = user_income
        user_address = input(" Enter the Address details ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Address'] = user_address

        print(f" New User account {create_user_ID} has been successfully created")

# Need to clarify this step,but program is running without any issues

        with open('Employee Details.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            csv_columns = ['User ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'Department', 'Salary', 'Address']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)

            writer.writeheader()
            for key,value in user_details.items():
                row = {'User ID': key}
                row.update(value)
                writer.writerow(row)

        process = input(" Do you want to continue the Account creation process (YES / NO ) : ").lower()
        if process == 'no':
            break

    elif user_input == 'view':
        user_ID = input("Enter the user_ID : ")
        print(user_details[user_ID])
        break

    else:
        print(" Please enter the proper command to execute (new / view)")

for detail in user_details.items():
    print(detail)
```

Comment: What do you think `writer.writeheader()` might do? And you are opening the CSV file in `a` for append mode - so your output gets written after everything that’s already there.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code. .. A minimal example for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with this file.tell () method, It is working fine !! anyhow thanks for all your answers.

```
with open('Employee Details.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
     csv_columns = ['User ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'Department', 'Salary', 'Address']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)

# using  file.tell we can verify the position whether there is any content in the position by specifying the value is 0

    if csvfile.tell() == 0:
       writer.writeheader()

    for key,value in user_details.items():
        row = {'User ID': key}
        row.update(value)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the while loop, check to see if the file exists; if it doesn't; create the file with the header.  In the loop just write rows.